# Proving an implicit equation has no orbits

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, implicit-function

Suppose we have the function $F(x,y)=x+y-a\log(x)$ where a is a constant and define the orbit by the implicit equation $F(x,y)=c$ where c is a constant. How can I formally prove that no orbit reaches the $y$-axis?

I can sketch the some level curves of this, but still I want to know if this is something that can be proven formally?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "orbit(s)" do  you mean level set(s)?  I see nothing here to think in terms of orbits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(x,y)$ is not defined when $x=0$.  So if an "orbit" is defined as the set of solutions of $F(x,y)=c$, it can't contain any point of the $y$ axis.

EDIT: Ah, so what's really going on here is that  $F(x,y) = c$ is an implicit
form for the trajectories of a system of differential equations: those are the "orbits".  You should have mentioned that in the first place.

Well, not only does the solution set of $F(x,y) = c$ not contain any point of the $y$ axis, it also has no limit points on the $y$ axis if $a\ne 0$, because $\lim_{x \to 0+} \log(x) = -\infty$.

Comment: Yes I did this, but then my teacher told me that F(0,y) being undefined is not a proof that no orbit reaches the y axis. In general my question is related to the SIR model when F is obtained via dividing the equation for I’ by S’ and then using separable ODE. So really I don’t know what to think about it. Don’t understand why stating F(0,y) is undefined shouldn’t be enough.

Comment: So making some simulations and by stating this, it should be enough to prove it?